# Tool or command to move multiple files from multiple folders into one place (without overwriting)

Tags: filemanager

I am currently working on recovering some logfiles from random backups that I made.
I have 48 files in 70+ folders.

How can I move these 48 files into one folder, without overwriting files with the same name? Most of these files have the same name, but different size, I checked with `fdupes`.

Comment: What do you want to do with files that have the same name ?

Comment: I want to keep them, renamed. (I will sort the files by the date it was created, so the name doesn't matter that much)

Answer (score 0):

Type this command in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open it) :

```
find $LOG_DIR -type f | xargs -I {} sh -c 'base=$(basename "$1"); name=${base%.*}; ext=${base##*.}; mv "$1" "$OUTPUT_DIR/$name`date +%N`.$ext"' -- {}
```

Basically, this will find all your files in $LOG_DIR (that you have to replace with the emplacement of the parent of your 70 folders), extract the name without path (*basename*), separate the name and the extension and then move them to $OUTPUT_PATH (replace by where you want them to go) and append the number of nanoseconds at this time (*data +%N*) to the name, so no overwrite.

PS: I've got a little help from there : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803296/modifying-replace-string-in-xargs)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I have tried the command, though I might have misunderstood the $LOG_DIR thing and the $OUTPUT_PATH. 
I have tried this way: ""find $USER Terminalling/a1command/extract_these_files/ ...."" and also: ""find Terminalling/a1command/extract_these_files/..."". Either way i got: ""mv: cannot stat ‘thisisalogfile.log’: No such file or directory"" or ""mv: target ‘Terminalling/a1command/excerpt/757786046thisisalogfile.log’ is not a directory"". Here is what i have done: http://pastebin.com/mZGvUp8t

Comment: My bad, this line only work if you're in the same folder than the files you want to move. I'll edit my answer. And what's Terminalling ? A folder ?

Comment: Yes, its a folder. I have tried the command from the parent directory, but same result. (and from within the folder where the file is, it only renamed it) I'm guessing the command needs recursive search in all existing subdirectories, and moving the found files to another folder.

Comment: Try this new line. I tested it with logs in a test folder, launching it from my home.

Comment: mv: cannot create regular file ‘/thisisalogfile412781517.log’: Permission denied.  ---tried the command as it is, from the parent folder

Comment: Your trying to create(or move) a file but you don't have the rights to write in the output folder. And if this is your whole trace, you tried to write in `/`, that's not good. Check your permissions or try with `sudo`.

Comment: Well, I was in a subdirectory inside /home, so its weird that it needs rights to create/move a file. In the meanwhile I have been searching, and found another command, though this one merges files with the same name... """find $HOME/music -name '*.*' -exec cp {} $HOME/new_music/ \;""" do you know of a way of how not to overwrite moved/copied files using that command?

Comment: Those two commands are practically the same. Using `-exec` or `xargs` will produce identical results. Can you pastebin the command and the result please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mjuqDGWM
 after that the files got copied in "excerpt" correctly (though some other files were overwritten)

Answer (score 0):

First use `find` as indicated above to locate the files you want to move:

```
find /dir/with/scattered/logs -type f
```

This will just print the list of files. If you're happy with it, simply use `cp` with the backup option, this will "make a backup of each existing destination file". Since you said names don't matter that much that should be OK. Backed-up files will have a "~" attached to the name. See `man cp` for some better control over this functionality.

```
find /dir/with/scattered/logs -type f -exec cp -b {} /destination/directory \;
```

This will copy files one by one, which is less efficient than using `xargs`, but for the amount of files you mention it shouldn't be an issue.